# Can I insert data in sqlite database and and select data from same table at same time?

Tags: sqlite

I have very large amount of data on server, and I am fetching this through api and saving it in database table in background. Can I now select the data from same table and show on UI at same time?

Comment: Have you tried this yet?  In the worst case scenario, perhaps some of the data you just brought in would not be available yet, but I expect your select should work.

Comment: If there is a lot of data, real time may be hard to maintain, but you could download it into your db every hour and then it can be searched from your own UI

Comment: Only in [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).